# How to override non-class members?

Tags: swift

I'm having problems trying to override non-class members but I get the error: "'override' can only be specified on class members".

How can I get around this?

```
override func ^(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int {
    return Int(pow(Double(lhs), Double(rhs)))
}
```

I thought it would work OK, but I didn't expect an error to come up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `override` in only file-scoped place. It uses within class scope.

Don't use `^` sign to make new function as you want. Here below is description of original function `^`:

```
/// Returns the result of performing a bitwise XOR operation on the two given
/// values.
///
/// A bitwise XOR operation, also known as an exclusive OR operation, results
/// in a value that has each bit set to `1` where *one or the other but not
/// both* of its arguments had that bit set to `1`. For example:
///
///     let x: UInt8 = 5          // 0b00000101
///     let y: UInt8 = 14         // 0b00001110
///     let z = x ^ y             // 0b00001011
///     // z == 11
///
/// - Parameters:
///   - lhs: An integer value.
///   - rhs: Another integer value.
public static func ^ (lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int
```